# Learning if the possible roots of an equation are different without resolving it

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there anyway to know if a given equation will have different roots (all of them different to each other).

Say: $x^3 - 17x^2 + 5x - \pi = 0$

Is there any property or theorem to know this for ANY grade 3 equation?

Comment: Use first derivative to find stationary points, then substitute those $x$s back to the cubic equation.

Comment: Use the discriminant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every cubic equation is of the form
$$
ax^3 + b x^2 + c x + d = 0
$$
with $a \neq 0$ and [we know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_nature_of_the_roots) that (at least) two of its roots are equal if and only if its discriminant is $0$, i.e. if and only if
$$
\Delta := 18abcd -4b^3d + b^2c^2 - 4ac^3 - 27a^2d^2 = 0
$$
In other words, a cubic equation has three distinct roots (real or complex) if and only if its discriminant is non-zero. Furthermore, if $\Delta > 0$ they are all real, while if $\Delta < 0$ one root is real and the other two are complex (and conjugate).

---

The discriminant for your example equation is
$$
18 \cdot 17 \cdot 5 \cdot \pi - 4 \cdot 17^3 \cdot \pi + 17^2 \cdot 5^2 - 4 \cdot 5^3 - 27 \cdot \pi^2
$$
which is non-zero (negative, more precisely) because $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: With "multiple roots" do you mean multiple AND DIFFERENT roots? I know it must have 3 roots, complex or real, I want to know if any of those are the same x1 != x2 != x3 .

Comment: @fiskk No, by "multiple roots" I mean roots with multiplicity greater than $1$. In other words, a cubic equation has two or more equal roots if and only if its discriminant is $0$, so all you need to do is check that it is non-zero...

Comment: Great crystal clear, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A polynomial $p(x)$ has multiple roots if and only if $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$ have a common non-constant factor. So in order to figure this out, run the Euclidean algorithm to find the greatest common divisor (using polynomial division with remainder) of $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$ and see if it is a constant or not.